# Installing Magento CE through Installatron in Cpanel - Yay or Nay?

Tags: install, installation

In the past I've paid an expert to install Magento CE on my servers, because despite being reasonably tech savvy, it looks like a daunting task to do manually. I'm starting a new store and recently discovered that I could do an 'easy' install of Magento using Installatron in Cpanel. Does anyone have any experience in doing this, and would you recommend it?

[image: Magento Install]

Comment: yes, you can do this using control panel,if controll panel have provide  the featue.. But it better to use any magento expert do this

Comment: having cPanel already Nay...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. There are far more important things:

1. NEVER CHANGE your live environment
2. use a local development environment
3. deploy code controlled (no FTP)
4. use a VCS (version control system) like git, svn, mercurial, ...

Answer (score 0):

Use it. The process is quite simple and there is an [official script](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh) from Magento to get the info from. 
If you have some time do 2 different installations one using the installer and one via SSH and compare the dirs with a [diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874090/linux-how-to-get-diff-between-all-files-inside-2-folders-that-are-on-the-web)

```
diff -ENwbur magentossh/ magentoinstaller/  | kompare -o -
```